# why networkpolicy ingress not working for my case

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I made deployment with 2 pods:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: nginx1
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        resources: {}
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
status: {}
```

Then exposed it with clusterip, then created a networkpolicy like below:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-network-policy
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx1
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          role: frontend
```

But when i request it via wget using busybox pod which DOES NOT contain the label (role=frontend), i still getting the html page of nginx.

I would like to know why ?

Any help would be really appriciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your k8s cluster is deployed with `Container Network Interface (CNI)` plugin that does not support network policies, it will not have an impact on it. From [k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#prerequisites):

> Network policies are implemented by the network plugin. To use network policies, you must be using a networking solution which **supports NetworkPolicy**. Creating a NetworkPolicy resource without a controller that implements **it will have no effect.**